# exec FATAL Executable name has embedded quote, split the arguments

Tags: cordova, ant, blackberry-webworks

I am trying to create a blackberry build using phonegap 2.7.0 and blackberry webworks SDK, but i am getting an error.
I am using "ant blackberry build" command to create blackberry build.

```
build:
[exec] [INFO] Parsing command line options  
[exec] [INFO] Parsing bbwp.properties  
[exec] [INFO] Validating application archive  
[exec] [INFO] Parsing config.xml  
[exec] [INFO] Populating application source  
[exec] [INFO] Compiling BlackBerry WebWorks application  
[exec] [FATAL] Executable name has embedded quote, split the arguments
```

I have searched it and found it is related with java jdk version.
I have downgraded the jdk and tried it but still i am getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because WebWorks is installed in a path with **whitespaces** like C:\Program Files, try reinstalling it on path like **C:\webworks**

Also reinstall your **Java 6 JDK (32 bits)** in a path without whitespaces because webworks copies the path in a *installvariables.properties* and *bbwp.properties*

Is recommendable to install all this stuff in non-whitespace paths because that could lead to other compiling problems.